# How to run Caret on a Supercomputer properly?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret, hpc

**Supercomputer Setup (Session Info)**

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.5.281/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin/libmkl_gf_lp64.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C              LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] caret_6.0-86    lattice_0.20-38 forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.5     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.0    
 [9] tibble_3.0.1    ggplot2_3.3.0   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6         lubridate_1.7.8      class_7.3-15         assertthat_0.2.1     ipred_0.9-9          foreach_1.5.0       
 [7] R6_2.4.1             cellranger_1.1.0     plyr_1.8.6           backports_1.1.7      stats4_3.6.3         reprex_0.3.0        
[13] httr_1.4.1           pillar_1.4.4         rlang_0.4.6          readxl_1.3.1         data.table_1.12.8    rstudioapi_0.11     
[19] rpart_4.1-15         Matrix_1.2-18        splines_3.6.3        gower_0.2.1          munsell_0.5.0        broom_0.5.6         
[25] compiler_3.6.3       modelr_0.1.8         pkgconfig_2.0.3      nnet_7.3-12          tidyselect_1.1.0     prodlim_2019.11.13  
[31] codetools_0.2-16     fansi_0.4.1          crayon_1.3.4         dbplyr_1.4.3         withr_2.2.0          ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2
[37] MASS_7.3-51.5        recipes_0.1.12       grid_3.6.3           nlme_3.1-144         jsonlite_1.6.1       gtable_0.3.0        
[43] lifecycle_0.2.0      DBI_1.1.0            magrittr_1.5         pROC_1.16.2          scales_1.1.1         cli_2.0.2           
[49] stringi_1.4.6        reshape2_1.4.4       fs_1.4.1             timeDate_3043.102    xml2_1.3.2           ellipsis_0.3.1      
[55] generics_0.0.2       vctrs_0.3.0          lava_1.6.7           iterators_1.0.12     tools_3.6.3          glue_1.4.1          
[61] hms_0.5.3            survival_3.1-8       colorspace_1.4-1     rvest_0.3.5          haven_2.2.0
```

The instance is a 0 GPU, 64 CPU and 320 GB Ram.

**Reproducible Example**

```
# packages
require(tidyverse)
require(caret)
require(parallel)

# nobs
n.obs = 100000
n.vars = 20

# generate data
class.data <- twoClassSim(
  n = n.obs,
  intercept = 0,
  linearVars = n.vars,
  noiseVars  = n.vars,
  corrVars = n.vars,
  ordinal = F
)



# generate Fold
set.seed(1903)
myFolds <- createMultiFolds(
  y = class.data$Class,
  k = 10,
  times = 3
)

# models;
algorithm <- c(
  
  # Regular Tree
  "rpart",
  
  # Random Forest
  "rf",
  
  # Gradient Boosted Machine
  "gbm"
)


# My control Object
myControl <- trainControl(
  index = myFolds,
  method = "repeatedcv",
  allowParallel = T,
  verboseIter = T
  
)


# model formula
model.formula <- as.formula(
  Class ~ .
)



# one model; test ####

# Generate CLuster
cl <- makeCluster(
  spec = 30
  # Was 10; 325
  # Was 20; 304
  # Was 30; 313
)


doParallel::registerDoParallel(
  cl = cl
)

system.time(
  baseline.model <- train(
    form = model.formula,
    data = class.data,
    method = algorithm[2],
    trControl = myControl,
    num.threads = 30
  )
)

stopCluster(
  cl = cl
)
```

**I never got any results?**

As of now, this algorithm has been running for 14 hours without any results yet. I have tried reducing the features such that it only has the relevant ones; this amounts to roughly 21 features. After a 6 hour run, I gave up on that as well.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it normal for an algorithm on such a computer to run for 12+ hours, before any results might appear?

And do you have any advice on how to approach such issues, such that I do not wake up to an error after many hours of run time?

Comment: A good engineering practice is to have an O( i^X . f^Y . c^Z . N^u . F^v ) scaling model, where ( N, F ) - are an obvious pair of strongest & often debated big-O scalers,  while ( i, f, c ) start to play their prime in doing HyperParameterSPACE searches. How many examples ( N ) did your code try to learn from? Having doubts with the code, as-is, did you try to run it first on 1E3 examples ( yes, just a thousand of 'em ), just to validate a PASS QA-step, that the code actually works safe in the new eco-system (inside realms of an HPC-infra | cluster, no matter how a 64-CPU host got abstracted)?

Comment: Im not sure that I understand your comment, to be honest. However, by default, Caret uses 3 different values of the hyperparameter mtry. I treated the 100000 obs set as my 'initial' sample; as the original sample that I am about to work with is roughly 1 million obs.

I dont know if my comment leaves us closer to an answer? :-)

**Edit**
Also, Im an Economist without any 'real' background in programming; so it is mainly trial and error.

Comment: No problem @Atiba - instead of waiting tens of hours / days to see (or never see) a result, tried to advise to "test" as-is code 1st & a TimeDOMAIN scaling. Start with a subset of ~1E3 samples to see if code produces ***any*** result at all. If & only if that did make a sense, measure code-execution times for a set of growing sub-sets 1E3, 2E3, 5E3, 1E4, 2E4, 5E4 samples you let into a training phase. That'll show you *--still-in-an-acceptable-amount-of-time--* a scaling of the code-execution time dependency on *N*-samples - a rough plot will show you times you are fair to expect for 1E6+ ones

Comment: Ah - of course. I should have derived that from your comment on the get-go. On an honest sidenote, I do not know anything about supercomputers. I thought 1E6 samples was easy as 1E3 on my own computer set up. Before I started the algorithm I thought it would take that amount of time, as it would making a cup of coffee! From your comment I see that high run times are expected....